# My eclipse fails to freeze the output of a java code

Tags: java, eclipse

I wrote the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SumOfDigits {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number:");
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    
    int temp=n;
    
    int sum=0;
    
    while(temp>0) {
        sum+=temp%10;
        temp/=10;
    }
System.out.println(sum);
    sc.close();
    }

}
```

But after running/executing, the output is shown but only for a second and then the console becomes blank.
Pls suggest the possible error

Comment: Are you actually running it within Eclipse or externally? Maybe there are other processes running in Eclipse and it switches to another console. You can select the console to view with the little dropdown menu and then select to "pin" it so it does not disappear again.

Comment: You should never call `.close()` on a `Scanner` that uses `System.in`. There is no need to close it and causes issues if you try to read anything from the console afterwards. It wouldn't even surprise me if removing it would fix the issue you are facing right now. (Although it could also be completely unrelated.)

Comment: @tobias_k I am running it in Eclipse only and previously it was working nicely but I am facing this issue from today

Comment: @ivar I tried removing it too, bt nothing happens

Comment: Have you tried restarting Eclipse?

Comment: @tobias_k Yes I have tried restarting Eclipse and also my PC bt the problem remains same.

Comment: The _Console_ view can display multiple outputs. Unless you have pinned it (which is not the case by default), the Console view will show the latest output. There is a button with which you can switch between the outputs. What is displayed in the header above the main text area?